# jQuery AJAX + ASMX - Internal Server Error on Dev but not Local

Tags: jquery, ajax, asmx

I have a page that, on load, calls the callMethod jquery function. This function calls a method on an ASMX page to get some data from the db. On success, it'll call another jQuery function. On error, it just alerts with the xhr.rsponseText.

On Localhost, this works fine. No issues. However, once I publish to Dev, I get a 500/internal server error, and since I'm not as familiar with AJAX, I'm not sure what I'm missing.

I don't think it's a db connection issue. I think there's something wrong with the AJAX/parameters/whatever is being passed not being parsed properly?

Any help would be super appreciated! Thank you in advance. :)

jQuery

```
    $(function () {
        callMethod("GetColumnsList", "setFieldList");
    });

    function callMethod(methodName, returnFunctionName, argData) {
    $.ajax({
        url: getUrl(methodName),
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        success: function (data) {
            if (returnFunctionName) {
                if (argData)
                    window[returnFunctionName](data, argData);
                else
                    window[returnFunctionName](data);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, error) {
            console.log("Failed the ajax operation.");
            console.log(xhr.status);
            console.log(error);
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
```

ASMX

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string GetColumnsList()
{
    var db = new MySqlConnectionStringEntities();
    var records = (from c in db.Fields
                   where c.IsDeleted == false
                   orderby c.Id
                   select new
                   {
                       c.Name,
                       c.Description
                   }).ToList();
    var resultStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Classes.FieldNameMap.GetAllFields(), Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
    });
    return resultStr;
}
```

Comment: Are you getting the url you expect in `getUrl` inside the ajax? (It might be unrelated.) Try to get the Event Log at the time of the error.

Comment: You were right. :) Apparently the url was parsing properly on localhost, but once it got pushed to dev, it wasn't resolving it. I had to update the url path to the webservice file. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be that Ajax wasn't finding the web service file.

I had code that stated:

```
function getUrl(name) {
    return "../../WebServices/Associates/Request.asmx/" + name;
}
```

I had to change the return path to "../WebServices/Associates/Request.asmx/" in order for it to work.  Previous path worked on local but not on dev possibly due to change in folder structure of the project on dev? Anyway, all fixed. Thanks for the help!